# Mobile App Credit Card SSL

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ssl, security

I'm a web developer, but I occasionally step over into doing some mobile app development here and there. A client recently asked me to help them develop a very simple app. The app is essentially just an HTML / jQuery form that the user fills out to reserve my clients service. Having heard a lot about phonegap, I decided to try it for the first time, along with jQuery mobile. Everything worked fine with the phonegap build, and after testing both iOS/Android work.

Although, part of the form requires users to enter their Credit Card information, so my client can book them with their own system. The card is never processed through the app, the information is just gathered and sent (via e-mail) to my client who uses their own payment gateway.

Since I used phonegap to build the app, I simply used action="https://www.my-website-with-ssl.php" on the form. Like I said, both iOS and Adroid are sending the e-mails(to my client) fine. But is this even secure?

Comment: Consider asking the guys over at [Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) for help

Comment: Thanks, good idea I'll go make a post over there.

Comment: I was able to go get help over at Security, if anyone else comes across this you can find the follow up here: [link](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30019/sending-secure-information-from-app-with-ssl)